# Uploading images on rails using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

So I am working on a simple classifieds app on rails. I am trying to implement image uploading via **carrierwave** and **minimagick**, it is well documented and I have followed numerous tutorials online already, they all more or less offer the same solutions for an app developed using **rails** and **SQlite**.

After implementing my code I don't receive any error messages or warnings, it simply doesn't upload the image. When I look up my database using *DB Browser for SQlite* every other field is filled out accordingly except for images which says null.

I am not including **images** attribute as a separate model. I want them to be simply part of my **ad** model

PS. This is my first post on Stackoverflow so please bear with me. Everything else works except images upload.

new.html.erb

```
<div class="new_ad_form row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">

 <%= form_for(@ad, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|%> 
 <%= render 'layouts/shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class= "new_ad_field">
    <%= f.label "title:" %>  <!-- f.object here refers to @ad -->
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    </div>
    <div class= "new_ad_field">
    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= f.select :category, @categories %><br>
    </div>
    <div class= "new_ad_field">
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.number_field(:price, in: 1.0..1000000, step: 0.5) %>
    </div>
    <div class= "new_ad_field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, size: "30x5" %>
    </div>
    <div class= "new_ad_field">
    <%= f.label :address %>
    <%= f.text_field :address %><br>
    </div>
    <div class= "new_ad_field">
    <%= f.label :state %>
    <%= f.select :state, @states, {}, :onChange=>"javascript: 
    $dc.select_city();" %>
    </div>
    <div class= "new_ad_field">
    <%= f.label :city %>
    <%= f.select :city, @cities %><br>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :images %><br>
        <%= f.file_field :images, :multiple => true %>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center"><%= f.submit "Post ad", class: "btn btn-
       large btn-primary" %></div>
 <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

ads_controller.rb

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
 def new
  #@user = current_user
  @ad = Ad.new
  @categories = ['Electronic equipment', 'Cars', "Clothing", "Phones"]
  @location = {"Abia": ["Abuja","Gusau", "Kaduna", "Kano", "Yola", "Lagos", 
             "Minna", "Keffi"],
             "Zamfara": ["Abuja","Gusau", "Kaduna", "Kano", "Yola", "Lagos", 
             "Minna", "Keffi"]}

  @states = @location.keys
  @cities = @location[@location.keys[0]]

 end

def show
  @user = current_user
  @ads = @user.ads.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def create

  @ad = current_user.ads.build(ad_params)
  if @ad.save
    flash[:success] = "ad created!"
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end

private

  def ad_params
    params.require(:ad).permit(:user_id, :title, :category, :description, 
    :price, :address, :city, :state, {images: []})
  end

end
```

ad.rb

```
class Ad < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user

validates :user_id, presence: true
#validates :images, presence: true

mount_uploader :images, ImagesUploader
serialize :images, JSON
end
```

images_uploader.rb

```
class ImagesUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

 include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

 storage :file

    def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end

   version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
   end

   def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

end
```

and of course in my gemfile I have

```
....................
  gem 'carrierwave' 
  gem 'mini_magick'
....................
```

config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb

```
require 'carrierwave'
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
```

The following is the the command line log. Basically I'm trying to figure out why it is rolling back the transaction.

```
Started POST "/ads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-19 14:22:00 -0400
Processing by AdsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"7ehxs5JEkuhVasFB0m8VQkVbPLEc1+q/xPJQMD1H5Fblw==", 
"ad"=>{"title"=>"sdasdfasdfaasdf", 
"category"=>"Electronic equipment", "price"=>"500", 
"description"=>"asdfasdfasdfwetqwerfasdfasdcvzx", 
"address"=>"asdfafawefasdfadf", "state"=>"Kaduna", "city"=>"Zaria", 
"images"=>[#
<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000001041d1a0 @tempfile=#
<Tempfile:C:/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170619-8456-
1i97f2t.jpg>, 
@original_filename="394502_10152051195495464_1783658057_n.jpg", 
@content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"ad[images][]\"; 
filename=\"394502_10152051195495464_1783658057_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: 
image/jpeg\r\n">]}, "commit"=>"Post ad"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? 
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 24], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
No template found for AdsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 1706ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the following line in your code:

`mount_uploader :images, ImagesUploader`

`mount_uploader` should be pluralised like this:

`mount_uploaders :images, ImagesUploader`

Answer (score -1):

U need to add some codes in `config/application.rb`  file

```
require 'carrierwave'
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
```

i think its working tryn this one

Comment: Thanks Velu however that didn't solve the problem, I already had that piece of code in my 'config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb' file